# Non-GPL alternative to semaphore

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

My module gets build error in Linux 3.16.

```
FATAL: modpost: GPL-incompatible module mymodule.ko uses GPL-only symbol 'lockdep_init_map'
```

I find it is caused by the use of semaphore. When I remove calling sema_init(), the error is gone. Semaphore is commonly used in the kernel, so I would like to know any alternate (or workaround) to avoid GPL issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are *mutexes* not suitable for you? Using of them is more convinient than semaphores, and doesn't require GPL-compatibility from the module.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.